# adb connection error (devices status is offline in windows7)

Tags: android, windows-7, offline

when i used eclipse in win7.(Notebook - NT530U4B)
my phone status is always  offline.
sometimes show too many same devices(but all devices is offline)

if I used usb storage. It works right.
eclipse works right in winXP(another desktop computer , same cable , same devices)

I used XT720(Motorola motoroi) & Su-640(LG optimus-Lte)

I tried 
     reinstall Driver
     adb kill & restart , reboot
     use another cable

how to remove this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your drivers. I recommend you uninstall the device through device manager( Windows Key + R > devmgmt.msc > [Enter] ) and try installing PDANet(tutorial here: http://www.topnotchtablets.com/installADBdriver ). PDANet is distributed with necessary drivers to allow Windows to automatically install the correct ADB drivers.

And double check that "USB Debugging" is enabled in the phone's settings menu, of course.

Comment: Glad that helped, this took me forever to figure out on my own when I first had to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Disable USB debugging on your android device and re-enable it. You may want to disconnect and reconnect the device as you do so.